# Java + MySQL - PreparedStatement troubles with encoding

Tags: java, mysql, encoding, prepared-statement

I got this program that interacts with MySQL. It works but acts strangely when non-ASCII occur in the statement. I'm using prepared statement:

```
public ResultSet executeQuery(Connection _conn, int _val1, String _val2) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement stmt = _conn.prepareStatement("SELECT c.name  FROM categories c,languages l WHERE c.language = l.id AND c.user = ? AND l.name = ?;");
    stmt.setInt(1, _val1);
    stmt.setString(2, _val2);
    return stmt.executeQuery();
}
```

It works fine unless I use something like "čččč" in _val2. Problem is somewhere in Java because when I prepare the statement a print it to stdout those characters are just "????". Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens when it don't work? And don't be fooled by the console, you may need to configure it to display other charsets than ANSI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding `characterEncoding=UTF-8` parameter to the end of your JDBC connection URL. Even set the table and column character set to *UTF-8.* This [article](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html#Databases) explains how to do that.

Comment: Yes. Or whatever the appropriate encoding in MySQL is I suppose? For the czech language it could also be ISO-8859-2.

Comment: @tbsalling Yes absolutely.

Comment: Actually, I think that the encoding of the source file containing the "čččč" might also matter. This is configured in the IDE/editor and must match the encoding stated/selected when preparing the JDBC connection.

Comment: Thanks, `characterEncoding=utf8` fixed it. I already had all the tables and fields set to UTF-8 so probably it must be done altogether.

Comment: Any ideas on WHERE to set this JDCB-connection url? Can't find it anywhere (in my netbeans project).. :p

Comment: @TorClaesson It can be as a hard coded String, in properties file, as a JNDI object ....